# Date and time merge and extract using r

Tags: r, excel

i have a data set entry and exit of mall, which contains 6 columns, the first columns is date/time. in first row the date is mention and after that the time entry based on am and pm for the dull day, than the date changes and again the time entries follows,this is every day process, the data set is huge.  my objective is to first bring the date and time as per date and one is it is merge need to extract the date and time separately in the 12 hrs clock format. 
data set is like as follows 
sample data set is as follows

```
12/30/2019                  
6:27:32 PM   Entry - New            Access Granted  111111  123456  Deo  
6:27:29 PM   Entry - New            Access Granted  222222  123456  Nijjar
6:26:46 PM   Exit New               Access Granted  333333  1234    Pathak
6:24:58 PM   Entry New              Access Granted  444444  12345   Rakholiya
6:24:39 PM   Exit - New             Access Granted  555555  54321   Rakholiya
6:24:22 PM  ENTRY_NEW               Access Granted  666666  65432   Kumar 
12/29/2019                  
6:27:32 PM   Entry - New            Access Granted  111111  123456  Deo  
6:27:29 PM   Entry - New            Access Granted  222222  123456  Nijjar
6:26:46 PM   Exit New               Access Granted  333333  1234    Pathak
6:24:58 PM   Entry New              Access Granted  444444  12345   Rakholiya
6:24:39 PM   Exit - New             Access Granted  555555  54321   Rakholiya
6:24:22 PM   ENTRY_NEW              Access Granted  666666  65432   Kumar
```

i am using following code

```
***list_all <- lapply(Tabnames, function(x) read_excel(path=filepath,sheet=x, col_names = F, col_types = c("text", "text" , "text" , "numeric","numeric","text" )))

DF2 <- rbind.fill(list_all) 

DF2$date <- "test"

for (j in 1: nrow(DF2)) 
{
    if (is.na(DF2[j,6]))
    {
        DF2[j,1] -> Date}
else{Date -> DF2$date[j]}
}***
```

it is very time taking.please suggest some good approach.

Comment: Why are you reading the file with `lapply`? That alone could add significantly to the time required to run your code. Why not use `readxl`, https://readxl.tidyverse.org/, which will load the file as a tibble. You can then manipulate date formats with with your own code or other packages such as `lubridate`, https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/

Comment: i tried but the problem is i have  27 workbook in one excel file, so i used lappy to mearge them  and creating the data frame .

Comment: my main problem is to bring time and date together . can you please suggest code for that

Answer (score 0):

If all the question asks for is to bring date and time together, the following code will do it.
The trick is to have `as.Date` *not* recognize the times-only elements of vector `data`, coercing them to `NA`. And use this to split the vector into segments starting with a date followed by times. Then it's a simple matter of pasting the first element (a date) with the others and converting to class `POSIXct`.

```
tmp <- as.Date(data, "%m/%d/%Y")
sp <- split(data, cumsum(!is.na(tmp)))
tmp <- lapply(sp, function(x){
  x <- trimws(x)
  paste(x[1], x[-1])
})
data <- as.POSIXct(unlist(tmp), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")

rm(sp, tmp)    # final clean up
```

**Data**

```
data <-
c("12/30/2019", "6:27:32 PM", "6:27:29 PM", "6:26:46 PM", "6:24:58 PM", 
"6:24:39 PM", "6:24:22 PM", "12/29/2019", "6:27:32 PM", "6:27:29 PM", 
"6:26:46 PM", "6:24:58 PM", "6:24:39 PM", "6:24:22 PM")
```

Comment: tried to run the following code , got the following error Error in as.Date.default(DF3, "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'DF3' to class “Date”

Comment: @dkv10 Try with `DF3$date`. You must note that the data example I posted is a vector, not a data.frame.

Comment: the data set is huge so i am using data frame , using the DF$date is also giving the same error.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the data structure. Can you post the output of `dput(head(DF3, 20))` in the question'? (Is it `DF`, `DF2` or `DF3`?)